# reuse firebase in multiple component

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry, first because I am really new to this, and this may seem like a very easy question. 
I have a firebase DB I use within `Main` component to display a list of data. 
Also, I created a new component, below, to display only one random item within the data: `WordOfTheDay` like so :

```
class WordOfTheDay extends Component{

  render(){

    return(
      <Card
        title='WORD OF THE DAY'
      >
              <ListView
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this._renderWordOfTheDay.bind(this)}
              enableEmptySections={true}
              />

      </Card>

      );

  }


 _renderWordOfTheDay(item) {
     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
     return (
      <ListItem
        title={
              <Text item={item}
               onPress={() =>
               navigate('Details', {...item} )}
               />
              }
        />
      );
  }

}
```

I have an error `null is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.dataSource')` :
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Ybe.png)

My question is how can I make a use of the database, should I rewrite all the ListenForItems, ComponentDidMount... ? in the new component ?

Comment: Is this all of the code for the component? You don't have any state defined. You should define state in constructor like `this.state={dataSrouce: "string data"}`

Comment: @MilanGulyas, I did this, but error is "Can't Find variable: firebaseApp"
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      items: [],
      loading: true
    };
    this.itemsRef = this.getRef().child('items').limitToLast(1);
    this._handleResults = this._handleResults.bind(this);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Start off by setting up an empty list as datasource:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
    };
}
```

Then fill it in componentWillMount like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.setState({
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.items)
    })
}
```

Comment: I added but got the error message : undefined is not an object (evaluating Object.Keys(dataBlobs[sectionID])

Comment: Thank you for your help!